# Ubuntu does not boot on mainboard with UEFI

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

Windows 7 64 bit and Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit were installed on a new SSD on a computer with old motherboard (no UEFI). Dual boot with GRUB2 worked perfectly well: Windows and Ubuntu could be executed and worked well.

Then I replaced the motherboard with a modern motherboard with UEFI.

GRUB2 starts, and I can select the different options. Windows and Memtest can be started and are working properly. Ubuntu does not start (hangs, when the dots are blinking).
(I am not sure about Ubuntu recovery mode?. Currently I am sitting at another computer...)

I tried to boot Ubuntu from a Live-CD. Ubuntu does not start (hangs, when the dots are blinking). I tried all possible options in UEFI-configuration (boot-order, secure-boot off, UEFI-mode...)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI says:
2. If the other systems (Windows, GNU/Linux...) of your computer are installed in Legacy (not-UEFI) mode, then you must install Ubuntu in Legacy mode too.

Because I installed Windows, Grub, and Ubuntu with the old motherboard, I suspect, that now I have to use legacy mode = CSM. Which I tried...

Any Ideas?
Here is a screenshot taken after removal of 'splash quiet':
[image: boot hangs]

Answer (score 1):

The fact that GRUB starts, and can start Windows, means that GRUB is starting in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. GRUB cannot switch boot modes (BIOS to EFI or EFI to BIOS), so GRUB must be trying to start Linux in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode, too. In other words, EFI support is *not* your issue. If you try messing with those settings in the firmware, or make EFI-related changes to your disk partitioning or boot loader configuration, you're only likely to make matters worse.

My guess is that you've got a problem with your video configuration, but it could be something else like disk issues. You might get some more clues this way:

1. When GRUB starts, highlight the Ubuntu entry, but do not press Enter.
2. Press the `e` key to edit the GRUB entry. A simple text editor will start.
3. Locate the kernel line and *remove* the words `quiet splash` from that line.
4. Start the entry. (There's a prompt for what key to press to do this at the bottom, but I don't recall what it is offhand.)

The result will be an attempt to start Ubuntu, but with verbose text-mode messages about the startup procedure displayed to the screen. Chances are this procedure will fail at some point. Take a photo of the screen and add it to your original question. That will have diagnostic information that may provide enough clues to solve the problem.

Comment: The hint concerning display maybe leads to the correct direction. Ubuntu and Windows were installed when two monitors were connected. Currently there only is one monitor connected at the DVI-output of the graphics card (unchanged to previous configuration with old motherboard)
When I remove the splash quiet at another PC which boots Ubuntu correctly, I see that around the time of the freezing, the graphics mode change...
But this does not explain why it is not possible to boot from Live-DVD.

Comment: Second monitor does not help...

Answer (score 0):

I tried several other Linux distributions: Most of them had the same problem. At some point during boot the system hangs. I could not even install Linux in a virtual machine under Windows. Knoppix and Slax seemed to work more ore less.

In Windows some applications did not work properly, e.g. Firefox very often crashed and was not able to finish downloads. The screen sometimes flickered. And after an evening of frustrating work I found the solution:
- It was NOT the old graphics-card, which might have a problem with the new motherboard.
- It was NOT the 64 bit version of Windows, which for some time had some very annoying problems with updates (installing hundreds of updates at shutdown, reverting them at system startup).
- It was NOT the 64 bit version of Firefox
- It was NOT the new SSD, which might have brought some timing issues (faster access) or rights issues (Windows was installed with another mainboard, but the same user name).
- It was NOT an issue concerning UEFI or legacy mode (as was the first suspicion)

**It was an issue with my CPU (which worked perfectly well for almost 5 years). I have an AMD Athlon II X3.
The new mainboard offered the possibility to 'activate' a 4th core and some 3rd-level cache, which I tried. BIOS then showed AMD Phenom X4... I was very happy, because the 4th core seemed to work correctly. Well, seemed...
Now I that I have deactivated the 4th core again, Windows is as stable as before, I can boot Linux from Live-USB, no screen flickering...**